# Pricing for adding specific AJAX Controls to your website?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, custom-server-controls

I am going to start and develop a e-commerce website for someone, i just wanted to now if i were to create som AJAX Controls for the site how much should i charge?

The kind of AJAX Control would be where a user clicks on a product and pops open a div element in the center of the screen with the product item and information and an add to basket button. The add to basket button will use an AJAX call and will perform the steps to add the item to the basket.

There will be other AJAX Controls i want to talk to him about but if i can have a general idea of how much this type of control would cost, then i can decide on how much other AJAX Controls can be priced.

i would love some feedback, and would be greatfull.

Thanks.

Comment: Off topic? If anything it belongs on programming, but not closed.

Comment: Probably belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ to get the best feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What is your hourly rate
2. Multiply this rate by the estimated # of hours it will take you

Comment: thank you everyone, i know this question shouldnt be asked here because its not a technical question, but i know there are so many programmers and developers here that have been in this situation. Thanks for all that viewed the question and thanks to everyone that gave me the feedback. I think i will go by charging how many hours it will take and multiplying it by my hourly rate. The AJAX Control i explained about in this question should take me about 2-3 hours and my hourly rate would be £15 an hour so £30-£60, is this reasonable do you think?

Comment: Ok i think £15 is too muc an hour, hm, woul £10 be ok, then i woul charge him £20-£30.

Comment: As a guide at my previous place we charge out developers at AU$120 (£75) an hour and business analysts out at AU$150 (£94) an hour.  At £10 an hour you're only making £20800 a year, assuming you've got 100% loading.

Answer (score 1):

It should be based on how much time it will take you to develop.  If you're doing time based billing, multiply the number of hours by your hourly rate.

If you're developing controls to be re-sold to other developers to use in their products, rather than building them to a single person, you should charge less per sale.  In this instance your development costs are high, but your production costs are low.  You can scale your sales by selling the same component to many people.

If you're doing a once off for a single client you can't scale it, your development costs *are* your production costs, and you only get one sale which is why you need to charge more.